How to understand the result of yarn queue status
When I run the following command to see the status of my queue:
$ yarn queue -status my-queue
Queue Information : 
Queue Name : my-queue
        State : RUNNING
        Capacity : 10.0%
        Current Capacity : 1100.0%
        Maximum Capacity : 100.0%
        Default Node Label expression : pool1
        Accessible Node Labels : pool1


I can't understand the Current Capacity : 1100.0%, how could it happen that the value is 1100.0%?

Do you have access to configuration file. The most probably reasons are:

Overcommitment of Resources: YARN allows overcommitting resources, meaning that it can allocate more resources to applications than what is physically available. This can lead to a situation where the queue's usage exceeds its configured capacity.
Preemption: If preemption is enabled, YARN can temporarily exceed the configured capacity to satisfy resource demands. This allows critical applications to get the necessary resources even if it means over-allocating temporarily.
Misconfiguration: There might be a misconfiguration in the YARN setup that allows the queue to exceed its maximum capacity.


Thanks @mohammed for the helpful answer!
